# Magento 2 PHPSTORM Xdebug Configuration setup

Tags: magento2, debugging, xdebug

How to setup and use Xdebug in Magento 2 which is very necessary tool for Magento 2.

Comment: please check this link : https://magenest.com/en/debug-magento-2-code-xdebug-phpstorm-1/

Answer (score 6):

I have setup Xdebug for PHPSTORM in Linux system these are the steps.

Step 1 :-

```
sudo apt-get install php-xdebug
```

Xdebug installation is up to you and after that please insure Xdebug is installed .

[image]

Step 2 :-

Now we need to add some setting in our php.ini file so first you need to check from where your configuration is being loaded.

[image]

Go to configuration loaded file.

```
/etc/php/7.1/apache2/php.ini
```

Add this setting last at you php.ini file

```
zend_extension="/usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.remote_autostart = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable = 0
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_mode = req
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
xdebug.remote_log="/var/log/xdebug/xdebug.log"
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
```

This is screen-cast of your file will be look like this.

[image]

Step 3:- PHPSTORM

Start Your PHPSTORM GO To File >> Settings

[image]

```
Make sure your xdebug.remote_port = 9000 and in your PHPSTORM setting Debug Port == 9000 must be the same.
```

Step :- 4 [ Setting are completed ! ]

Now Go to your PHPSTORM in Menu >> Run >> Start Listing For Php Debug Connection

```
Start this setting before launching your project url in your browser.
```

Screen- Cast

[image]

Now open you browser and start your project and add session key to your url so that phpstorm inform to start debugging.

```
http://localhost/magento223?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=18200
?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=18200  == This is phpstorm session key.
```

That's all to configure Xdebug in PHPSTORM do let me know if you face any issues.

Comment: How to you get session key?

Comment: @xanka just add ?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=18200 after your url

Comment: after the 2nd step, we may need to restart apache: sudo systemctl restart apache2